# RecyclerView não mostra os dados da lista

Tags: php, java, android, android-adapter

Tenho um problema que, ao tentar listar os dados no `RecyclerView` ele não mostra os registros, no Debug verifico que os registro são inseridos na lista '`ArrayList`', segue o código.

Método `ListarArquivosdoFTP` onde ele conecta com o FTP e retorna a string dos itens e joga a lista para o `Adapter`:

```
public void ListarArquivosdoFTP() {

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Recibo recibo = null;
                    classe_FTP ClienteFTP = new classe_FTP();
                    ClienteFTP.Conectar("ftp.meuhost.com.br", "usuario", "senha", 21);
                    FTPFile[] arquivos = ClienteFTP.Dir("/caminho");
                    if (arquivos != null) {
                        int length = arquivos.length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                            FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
                            if (f.isFile()) {
                                recibo = new Recibo();
                                recibo.setRecibo(f.getName());
                                ArquivosFTP.add(recibo);
                            }
                        }
                        ReciboAdapter adapter = new ReciboAdapter(ArquivosFTP);
                        recyclerRecibo.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

E o meu `Adapter` completo:

```
public class ReciboAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReciboAdapter.ReciboHolder> {

    List<Recibo> listaRecibo;

    public ReciboAdapter(List<Recibo> listaRecibo) {
        this.listaRecibo = listaRecibo;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReciboHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View vista = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_recibo, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new ReciboHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReciboHolder reciboHolder, int i) {

        reciboHolder.txtRecibo.setText(listaRecibo.get(i).getRecibo().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaRecibo.size();
    }

    public class ReciboHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtRecibo;

        public ReciboHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtRecibo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRecibo);
        }
    }
}
```

E no `onCreateView` está assim:

```
recyclerRecibo = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
recyclerRecibo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
recyclerRecibo.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Acho que é pq faltou o LayoutManager, adiciona essa linha `recyclerRecibo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));` antes de setar o adapter

Comment: Eu já tenho no onCreateView, vou adicionar na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso deve funcionar para você:

```
    public void ListarArquivosdoFTP() {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Recibo recibo = null;
                classe_FTP ClienteFTP = new classe_FTP();
                ClienteFTP.Conectar("ftp.meuhost.com.br", "usuario", "senha", 21);
                FTPFile[] arquivos = ClienteFTP.Dir("/caminho");
                if (arquivos != null) {
                    int length = arquivos.length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                        FTPFile f = arquivos[i];
                        if (f.isFile()) {
                            recibo = new Recibo();
                            recibo.setRecibo(f.getName());
                            ArquivosFTP.add(recibo);
                        }
                    }
                    ReciboAdapter adapter = new ReciboAdapter(ArquivosFTP);
                    recyclerRecibo = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
                    recyclerRecibo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                    recyclerRecibo.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerRecibo.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Por fim, no onCreateView(), chame o método ListarArquivosFTP();

Note: O `recyclerRecibo.setAdapter(adapter);` tem que ser a última de todas as configurações do RecyclerView.